# Calculating pH of reaction mixture of silver nitrate and ascorbic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism

I am designing an experiment but before I do, I wanted to understand if the following method is right to calculate the expected $\mathrm{pH}$ when I mix $\pu{0.736 M}$ $\ce{AgNO3}$ and $\ce{C6H8O6}$.

I want the $\ce{AgNO3}$ to be the limiting reactant for this reaction. I think chemical equation will be: 
$$\ce{2AgNO3 + C6H8O6 <=> 2Ag (s) + C6H6O6 + 2HNO3},$$

which would mean that there would be 2 hydrogen ions.

$$\ce{2Ag+ + C6H8O6 <=> 2Ag (s) + C6H6O6 + 2H+}$$

If I start with $\pu{0.736M}$ $\ce{AgNO3}$ and I plan to have that in $\pu{1L}$ water solution (also intend the $\ce{C6H8O6}$ to be in $\pu{1L}$ water solution), then the moles of hydrogen generated will be:
$$\pu{0.736 mol} \ \ce{H+}$$

This would mean the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ will be 
$$\frac{\pu{0.736 mol}}{\pu{2L}} = \pu{0.368M}$$

So the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution would be $-\log 0.368  = 0.434$? This number does not seem right since ascorbic is a weak acid, is my logic correct?

Comment: If you start equimolar and the reaction goes to completion, there is no more ascorbic acid. What pH do you expect at the beginning of the reaction?

Comment: To rephrase Karsten's comment - The acid build up in the solution is the result of a redox reaction where ascorbic acid is oxidized to dehydroascorbic acid, not the dissociation of ascorbic acid.

Comment: That is quite a lot of silver. Is that experiment worthy of it ?

Comment: Would the pH of ascorbic acid when added to water be the pH in the reaction with silver nitrate? Is that what you mean @MaxW

Comment: user510 - If you don't add any other acid, then yes the initial pH would be due to the dissociation of ascorbic acid.

Comment: Ok so the pH initial pH will be the pH with silver nitrate? Wouldn't the extra volume increase the pH? Because you initially put x mol ascorbic acid in 1L water solution but then you add it to another 1L solution, wouldn't this impact pH?

Comment: Poutnik has a good point. I'd sure use smaller quantities of solution until I knew the reaction was going to work like I wanted. 10 ml of each would reduce the cost of the experiment to 1% of using 1 liter quantities.

Comment: @user510 yes diluting would *increase* the pH not lower it. // *pH increase* indicates the solution is less acidic, *pH decrease* means more acidic.

Comment: Yes sorry that is what i meant. So that is what I was trying to calculate, how much the pH will increase by

Comment: Whether it is worked or not, you should make it more diluted. As Poutnik pointed out, this silver nitrate would cost you an upside of $250.00.

Comment: Ok point considered but could you help me in understanding how the pH will change when ascorbic acid solution will be added to the silver nitrate solution? How can I calculate that?

Comment: With high concentration of reagents, there would possible the created nitric acid would be slowly dissolving silver back to the nitrate.

Answer (score -1):

For solutions of weak acids and with simplifying assumptions [H+]=[A-], [A-] << [HA ], there is formula:

$$\mathrm{pH}=\frac12(\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} - \log {c})\tag{1}$$

For our case, if the stoichiometric ascorbic acid concentration $0.368/2=\pu{0.184 mol/L}$ is used:

$$\mathrm{pH}=\frac12(4.1 - \log {0.184}) \simeq 2.42\tag{2}$$

If reaction is completed, $\mathrm{pH}$ would be given by $\ce{HNO3}$ only.

**Situation would get complicated, if nitric acid starts to react with metallic silver or residual ascorbic acid. These side reactions would decrease mineral and eventually also organic acidity.**

$$\ce{3 Ag + 4 HNO3 -> 3 AgNO3 + 2 H2O + NO}$$
$$\ce{3 C6H8O6 + 2 HNO3 -> 3 C6H6O6 + 4 H2O + 2 NO}$$

---

If more of the ascorbic acid is used, initial $\mathrm{pH}$ is again given by the above equation.

The ending $\mathrm{pH}$ is given by equation:

$$[\ce{H+}]= c_1 + [\ce{A-}]\simeq K_\mathrm{a}\frac{c_2}{[\ce{A-}]}\tag{3}$$

where $c_1$ is the nitric acid concentration, $c_2$ is the residual ascorbic acid concentration. and the right equation side is taken from $(1)$

Concentration of $\ce{H+}$ is equal to sum of $\ce{HNO3}$ concentration $c_1$ + $\ce{H+} from weak acid, that is equal to A- concentration ( HA -> H+ + A-). The latter is then approx equal to simplified extression derived from the acid dissociation constant.

$$c_1 \cdot  [\ce{A-}]  + {[\ce{A-}]}^2 - K_\mathrm{a}\cdot c_2  \simeq 0 \tag{4} $$

$$[\ce{A-}]=\frac{-c_1 + \sqrt{{c_1}^2+4\cdot c_1\cdot c_2 \cdot K_\mathrm{a}}}{2} \tag{5}   $$

From (3):

$$[\ce{H+}]=\frac{c_1 + \sqrt{{c_1}^2+4\cdot c_1\cdot c_2 \cdot K_\mathrm{a}}}{2} \tag{6}  $$

$$[\ce{H+}]=c_1 \cdot \frac{1 + \sqrt{1+ \frac{4\cdot c_2 \cdot K_\mathrm{a}}{c_1}}}{2} \tag{7}  $$

In the case by we use acid concentration twice as much as stoichiometric one, then $c_1 = 2c_2$. As $K_\mathrm{a}=\pu{7.94e-5}$:

$$[\ce{H+}]=c_1 \cdot \frac{1 + \sqrt{1+ 2 \cdot K_\mathrm{a}}}{2} \simeq c_1 \cdot  1.00004 \tag{8}  $$

You can see the dissociation of the weak acid is almost suppressed by $\ce{H+}$ from nitric acid, so we can neglect the weak acid contribution to $\mathrm{pH}$.

Comment: Could you explain how eq (3) was derived

Comment: Ok so 0.1 M $\ce{AgNO3}$ will have pH then of essentially -log(0.1) = 1?

Comment: But if it reacts with ascorbic acid the pH will still be close to 1 which you described above because the H+ concentration will be dominated by nitric acid

Comment: Ok I see. I am going to add 1.25 times stoichiometry concentration (to make sure silver nitrate is limiting) so I do not think that will drive up the pH of the initially $\ce{AgNO3}$ solution

Comment: is c1 = $\frac{\sqrt {0.736 x K_b}}{Volume}$?

Comment: Also, if I start with 0.736 moles (0.736 M) $\ce{AgNO3}$ and 0.368 moles (0.368M) ascorbic acid, by stoichiometry, I should get 0.736 moles hydrogen ions. However, by using $\ce{[H+] = c1 + [A-]}$ I would get total hydrogen concentration of 0.736+0.368 = 1.104 x 2 L = 2.208 moles hydrogen ions and not 0.736 moles that I should get by stoichiometry?

Comment: How is this accounting for the change in volume that will occur from mixing the two solutions?

Comment: If c1 = 0.368 mol / L then the pH = 0.434. Isn’t this very low? Because it is a salt reacting with a weak acid I feel like the pH cannot be below 1.

Comment: Is my logic correct?

Comment: Right, my concern was if the pH is so low I probably cannot use stainless steel equipment to mix the reaction (which is what I have been using but I have not seen any eating away of the steel that would happen at such low pH causing my doubts of if the pH could get this low). It is for reduction purposes, therefore, I am using ascorbic acid (which should give the ascorbate ion). If you could please clarify what you meant by "better is using ascorbate, or hydrogenascorbate" that would be very helpful.

Comment: Ya sorry I got it. But why would research paper just talk about Ascorbic acid rather than using the ion? Could it be they use dispersants which convert the Ascorbic acid to its ionic nature before mixing it with the silver?

Comment: Yes I was looking into that but the reactions become complex adding mix of all three with all the intermediates.

Comment: Wait I am confused again, if the H+ is coming from the ascorbic acid to begin with which is a weak acid, how can the product get so acidic. Sure, nitric acid is the product but the hydrogen ion is coming from the ascorbic acid dissociation so there should not be as many hydrogen ions to begin with

Comment: Right but only a small fraction of ascorbic acid will dissociate into hydrogen ions? So I guess the 0.184 mol/L of ascorbic acid you begin with, only a small fraction of that, maybe 0.01 moles hydrogen ions are  produced, so I am confused how then in the product side (by stoichiometry), there would be 0.368 mol/L

Comment: What happens to the equilibrium reaction when something is eating the product ?

Comment: to regain equilibrium it will produce more of the product? But how does it get more hydrogen ion from?

Comment: Write all equations and think.

Comment: Well the only places it can get it from is ascorbic acid or water. I do not think the acid will dissolve more under these conditions so then I am guessing it is coming from $\ce{H2O}$

Comment: Think longer. H2Asc <=> 2 H+ + Asc^2-. Asc^2- + 2 Ag+ -> Asc + 2 Ag. What will remain, if there is stoichiometric ratio AgNO3 and H2Asc ? H+ and NO3-.